# Amazon AWS version control

Tags: php, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm managing a website on Amazon Ec2 instance for a while now.
Since I'm the only developer and it was used for sandbox I just had one instance running a LAMP image and I would upload locally developed stuff using FTP to review (sandbox mode).

Since I'm gaining audience, I want to take this one step forward to setting up a development environment so I can both manage more developers working on the project, and have version control for backup and easy deployment of newly developed code to the users.

How do I manage different environments on the same instance? I wan't a development environment, and production environment, preferably easily managed. It goes both for the code and the data within an sql database. How do I let other users gain access without sharing my set of keys?

Was looking into elastic beanstalk but it seems to be effective when multiple instances are used and I'll admit, I didn't understand much about how it works.

I guess I'm asking - what is the correct way to develop web applications on amazon AWS services

Comment: I would recommend looking into [CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/). You can create production and development stacks.

Answer (score 0):

My assumptions here:

- You are running Apache
- You have already configured your domain so that both mysite.com and
  test.mysite.com have **A records** pointing to the IP address of your
  EC2 instance.

Your Apache web server is configured to handle the [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) mysite.com, e.g. in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default, or similar to the [documentation on Drupal.com](https://www.drupal.org/node/111238):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName drupalsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite-production/
        <Directory /var/www/mysite-production/>
                Options +FollowSymLinks Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, you need to create a second VirtualHost that maps to a subdomain only:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.drupalsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite-test/
        <Directory /var/www/mysite-test/>
                Options +FollowSymLinks Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Save this in your Apache configuration file and run /etc/init.d/apache2 reload – now any request to test.mysite.com will point to the other directory.

Make sure you should configure your TEST site instance to use another database than the production server. It would also be good to secure the testing installation from access by unauthorized users and search engines. An .htpasswd lock or a restriction based on IP addres using the mod_access directives.